# Query and group correct towards data in a azure table storage and post it to an API in correct nested .json format

Tags: c#, json, nested, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a lot data stored in an azure table storage table (string datatype).

I want to post only certain of these fields to an API every x minute in a .json format using an azure function with timer trigger. Everything is good but:

The format of the json is currently **including** square brackets, which I'm trying to **remove** without any sucess:

The most important is to remove the brackets, so maybe I can "hardcode" something to remove the brackets? I have used a lot of time to get it in correct "grouping" format. Can it be done in a much easier way?

```
{
   "Test":[
      {
         "name":"Tom"
      }
   ],
   "Info":[
      {
         "Weight":"122",
         "Age":"22"
      }
   ],
   "License":[
      {
         "number":"2222312"
      }
   ]
}
```

**First**:
I'm querying the data in the azure table storage:

```
        public async Task Run(
        [TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
        [Table("TestTable", Connection = "STORAGE-ConnectionString")] CloudTable TestTable,
       ICollector<string> events,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            TableContinuationToken token = null;
            List<PersonEntity> Entities = new List<PersonEntity>();
            do
            {
              var query = new TableQuery<PersonEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Status"
             , QueryComparisons.Equal, "NEW"));

                var result = await TestTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
                
                Entities.AddRange(result.Results);
                token = result.ContinuationToken;
               
            } while (token != null);
```

**Secondly**: I'm trying to collect only certain of the fields in the Azure table with the following code.

```
                IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, PersonEntity>> groupedEntities = Entities.GroupBy(x => x.PartitionKey);

            foreach (IGrouping<string, PersonEntity> group in groupedEntities)

            {
                PersonEntity baseEntity = group.First();

                var personBooking = new PersonBookingModel

                {
                Test = group.Select(x => new PersonBookingRouteModel 
                    {
                    name=x.PersonName.ToString()
                    }).ToList(),
                 Info = group.Select(x => new PersonBookingGoodsModel
                 {
                     Weight= x.PersonWeight.ToString(),
                     Age = x.PersonAge.ToString()
                 }).ToList(),
                 License = group.Select(x => new PersonBookingDriverModel
                 {
                     number = x.LicenceNumber.ToString(),                             
                 }).ToList()
                };
```

**Furthermore**:

```
try
                        {
                            var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personBooking);
                            using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                            {
                                if (payload == "")
                                {
                                    log.LogWarning("No payload created sucessfully");
                                }
                            else {
                                    log.LogWarning(payload); 
                                        }
                     
                           
                                latestResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("API-Endpoint"), content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                                if (latestResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    log.LogWarning("Response with endpoint");
                                }
                                string data = await latestResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**Desired output without brackets need to be:**

```
{
   "Test":
      {
         "name":"Tom"
      }
   ,
   "Info":
      {
         "Weight":"122",
         "Age":"22"
      }
   ,
   "License":
      {
         "number":"2222312"
      }
   
}
```

Comment: square brackets are arrays. I suggest you change your code so that this data is not represented as an array. This might be as simple as removing `.ToList()` from your code. I guess you would also need to change the definiiton of `PersonEntity` so that these attributes aren't collections.

Comment: Hmm, I tried but it was to much errors. 
Solved this the hard way with 
" var res = payload.Replace ("[","").Replace ("]",""); "

Answer (score 0):

As per the above comments, I'm converting your comment as answer so that may help other community members:

So after changing the code to this-

```
var res = payload.Replace ("[","").Replace ("]","");
```

Hopefully resolved your issue.